# Как повторно выполнить JSON-запрос, если сервер возвращает ошибку 500

Tags: javascript, json

Вот такая проблема. JS-скрипт берет данные из JSON с урла API и обрабатывает их.
Код создания запроса взял с MDN:

````
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL, true);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
request.onload = function() {
  var contratti = request.response;
  createContratti(contratti);
}; ```

Если сервер возвращает данные выполняется функция и все работает. Но по каким-то причинам иногда сервер возвращает ошибку 500. И тогда ничего не работает. Если обновить страницу, через секунду все опять ок, сервер возвращает данные и все ок. А через секунду опять может быть 500.
Вопрос такой, как автоматически повторно отправить запрос (или выполнить весь код) если статус ответа не 200?
````

Comment: Выделить код в функцию. Добавить в обработчик `onload` проверку: если `this.status == 500`, то повторно вызвать функцию

Comment: @ioprst пробовал, не работает. Можно пример кода?

Answer (score 1):

Выделите запрос в функцию (например `req`). В обработчик `onload` добавьте проверку статуса. Если статус равен `500`, то снова вызывайте функцию (`req`). Если статус равен `200`, обрабатывайте результат.

```
function req() {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/get', true);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 500) {
        console.log('Ошибка 500');
        req();
    } else if (this.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.response);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Нет, не работает. Все равно рандомно выдает то 500 и не может получить данные, то получает данные и все ок.

Comment: Вы спросили "как повторно выполнить запрос, если статус ответа не 200?".

Comment: Нет, я без претензий. Спасибо за потраченное время. Просто говорю, что суть решения должна по идее быть - выполнять запрос, пока не будет ответа 200, и скрипт не получит данные.А это решение так не работает. То есть я тоже думал, что в теории должно бы. На практике все равно не добирается до 200, а выводит 500. И все равно спасибо, еще раз.

Comment: Что за API используете? Я могу получить к нему доступ?

Comment: Нет, это кастомный API бек-энщики написали. И он на локалке к тому же пока.

Comment: Мне просто интересно. Вы сказали, что "это решение так не работает". А как оно работает? Я запустил простенькое приложение на Flask (https://ideone.com/X3HwZl), в котором объявил запрос, который возвращает либо статус 500 (90%), либо 200 (10%). При нажатии на кнопку запрос серверу отправляется до тех пор, пока не будет получен статус 200.

Comment: Интересно. Я тоже смотрю, в теории должно так и работать. Што ж, буду разбираться. Спасибо за ответы